# Gmail iOS Modal View Transition

Tags: ios, animation, gmail

Just wondering if anyone have tried to replicate the transition that is used for presenting modal views in Gmail iOS? It looks darn gorgeous and refreshing from the pop up from bottom animation.

[image]

Comment: Yeah. The animation is pretty good. I guess it can be reproduced with a custom segue that does some 3D transformation and scale of the `sourceViewController` and just presents the `destinationViewController` as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you're referring to the push-back transition when displaying the modal view controller? If so, then it's the one that the National Geographic Park Guides app first introduced and someone has [released their replica of it over on Github](https://github.com/kentnguyen/KNSemiModalViewController). This one is only a partial screen modal, but could be modified to mimic the full view that the Gmail app does.

Answer (score 0):

How about using this? Detailed animation, there is a need to develop a little more.
https://github.com/ucu072/HCPushBackAnimation

Answer (score 0):

I created a UIViewController category to mimic this type of modal animation. It is called [MFFadeBackModalAnimation](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFFadeBackModalAnimation). It wraps around the native API for presenting and dismissing view controllers so it should integrate well with your existing app.